# Andriod Navigation Component 2.1.0 with java

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-architecture-navigation

When I try to use the android navigation component on java. It doesnt work well with the navigation drawer out of the box. I'm able to execute everything except for navigating to the fragments from the navigation drawer. 
I'm working on a project that I needed to get out of the way real quick and wanted to complete it with java which I am more experienced in. Has anyone been able to hack this?

```
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.1.0'
```

MainActivity onCreate

```
rootLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    NavHostFragment navHostFragment = (NavHostFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    navController = navHostFragment.getNavController();

    mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(navController.getGraph())
            .setDrawerLayout(drawerLayout)
            .build();

    drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    //setup navigation
    NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
    mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
            R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_claims, R.id.nav_products,R.id.nav_deliveries, R.id.nav_quotes,
            R.id.nav_policies, R.id.nav_payment,R.id.nav_about,R.id.nav_contact)
            .setDrawerLayout(drawerLayout)
            .build();

    //setup action bar
    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
```

PS:The id's on mobile_navigation.xml and activity_main_drawer.xml are identical. So no problems there.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. It's a bit of a wierd one but oh well... You need to make sure the include for app_bar_main comes before the NavigationView in your activity e.g activity_main

```
<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    app:itemTextColor="@android:color/white"
    app:itemIconTint="@android:color/white"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
    android:isScrollContainer="true"
    android:saveEnabled="true"/>
```